# Item does not rotate with integrating jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

After looking at several options to rotate the text vertically I concluded that [jangle](http://corydorning.com/demos/jangle) jQuery option is the best one. Very easy to implement! However, I ran into an issue with IE browser. I tested your demo and it works great, but when I added to my page is having a problem… Please see [BBBB label][2], it remains horizontal.

It works great in FF, Safari and Chrome, but IE…

What am I missing here? Is there some sort of conflict?

Comment: IE not showing the same output as FF, Safari and Chrome?? Blasphemy!

Comment: I'm used to IE misbehave regularly. But the demo worked fine in IE...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `position:relative` in IE and it works. Must be `position:absolute;`

Comment: That element has position:asolute. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: You can try assigning `position:absolute !important;` just to see if it's able to be forced, then you can look into a less hacky solution. Might need to tweak the CSS in the plugin.

Comment: Not sure what puts that inline position... I added position:absolute !important; inline as well and it flips now, just a bit off to the side, but I can tweak it for IE. Thanks for the tip!